How would I turn my .NET console app into a screensaver?
I developed a C# application that continuously displays a binary counting sequence from 0 to 255. This visual output is intended to mimic the falling rain effect often seen in movies, but represented in binary code. My goal is to have this visual output displayed on my computer monitor when the system enters an idle, inactive state.
The Challenges:
I've attempted to transform my application into a format compatible with the idle state display mechanism. My approach involved building the program directly trying two different methods:

Making the application a Windows Forms Application

Building it as a Console application


I then attempted to alter this file's extension to correspond with the expected type for idle state programs. After changing the file extension, I then attempted to deploy the program using the standard right-click and "install" procedure, as if it was an existing idle state display program.
However, this process has not been successful. The idle state display preview fails to launch, even though the program appears in the configuration settings. It seems the program runs in the background but is not visible on the monitor when the system becomes inactive.
The Question:
How can I modify my C# program, which effectively simulates the desired visual effect within a console environment, so that it correctly functions as a visual display during the computer's idle state? Essentially, how do I bridge the gap between the console output and the expected format and behavior for a program that visually activates during system inactivity?
My code successfully creates the visual I'm aiming for, but I'm struggling to adapt it to operate during the computer's idle period. When renamed with the appropriate extension for these kinds of programs, it simply runs without appearing on the screen.
idle state program settings — an image of the preview window where it fails to launch as expected. This happens after I press 'preview'.
Here is my code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace BinaryCodeScreensaver
{
    class BinaryCode
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int matrixCode = 0;
            int screenHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
            int screenWidth = Console.WindowWidth / 9;
            List<string> screenLines = new List<string>();
            List<int> currentLines = new List<int>();
            List<int> currentColumns = new List<int>();
            List<int> columnDelays = new List<int>();
            Random random = new Random();
            ConsoleColor currentColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            bool pageFilled = false; // Flag to track if the page is filled
            string symbols = "ÄÅÆÇÐÉÑÖØÜßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ"; // String of possible symbols

            // Initialize screen lines
            for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < screenHeight; lineIndex++)
            {
                screenLines.Add("");
            }

            currentLines.Add(0);
            currentColumns.Add(0);
            columnDelays.Add(0);

            while (true)
            {
                // Generate new matrix code and add new columns
                if (matrixCode >= 255)
                {
                    matrixCode = 0;

                    if (currentLines.Count < screenWidth)
                    {
                        currentLines.Add(0);
                        currentColumns.Add(currentLines.Count - 1);
                        columnDelays.Add(random.Next(50));
                    }

                    currentColor = GetRandomGreenShade(random);
                }

                // Iterate over columns and update characters
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < currentLines.Count; columnIndex++)
                {
                    if (columnDelays[columnIndex] > 0)
                    {
                        columnDelays[columnIndex]--;
                        continue;
                    }

                    int currentLine = currentLines[columnIndex];
                    int currentColumn = currentColumns[columnIndex];

                    string binaryString = Convert.ToString(matrixCode, 2).PadLeft(8, '0') + " ";

                    string previousString = "";
                    if (screenLines[currentLine].Length > currentColumn * 9)
                    {
                        previousString = screenLines[currentLine].Substring(currentColumn * 9, 9);
                    }

                    screenLines[currentLine] = screenLines[currentLine].PadRight(currentColumn * 9) + binaryString;

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(currentColumn * 9, currentLine);
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', binaryString.Length));
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(currentColumn * 9, currentLine);

                    // Output characters with color and effects
                    for (int characterIndex = 0; characterIndex < binaryString.Length - 1; characterIndex++)
                    {
                        if (characterIndex < previousString.Length && binaryString[characterIndex] != previousString[characterIndex])
                        {
                            ConsoleColor newGreenShade = currentColor;
                            while (newGreenShade == currentColor)
                            {
                                newGreenShade = GetRandomGreenShade(random);
                            }
                            Console.ForegroundColor = newGreenShade;

                            // Apply random opacity to this character
                            if (pageFilled && random.Next(100) < 60) // 60% chance of opacity change
                            {
                                int opacityLevel = random.Next(1, 4); // Generate random opacity level (1-3)
                                switch (opacityLevel)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            // Replace with a random symbol with a green shade
                            if (pageFilled && random.Next(100) < 5) // 5% chance of symbol replacement
                            {
                                int randomSymbolIndex = random.Next(symbols.Length);
                                Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomGreenShade(random);
                                Console.Write(symbols[randomSymbolIndex]);
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (previousString.Length > characterIndex && previousString[characterIndex] == '0')
                            {
                                Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomGreenShade(random);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write(binaryString[characterIndex]);
                    }
                    Console.ResetColor();

                    // Update line and column positions
                    currentLines[columnIndex]++;

                    if (currentLines[columnIndex] >= screenHeight)
                    {
                        currentLines[columnIndex] = 0;
                        currentColumns[columnIndex]++;

                        if (currentColumns[columnIndex] >= screenWidth)
                        {
                            currentColumns[columnIndex] = 0;
                            pageFilled = true; // Page is filled when all columns are filled
                        }
                    }
                }

                matrixCode++;

                if (!pageFilled)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }
            }
        }

        // Generate a random shade of green
        static ConsoleColor GetRandomGreenShade(Random random)
        {
            int greenValue = random.Next(100, 256);
            ConsoleColor greenShade = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;

            if (greenValue > 200)
            {
                greenShade = ConsoleColor.Green;
            }
            else if (greenValue > 150)
            {
                greenShade = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            }

            return greenShade; // Return the generated color
        }
    }
}

I tried recreating it as a Form and that did not work.

Creating a Screen Saver with C# by Frank McCown (using mostly Windows Forms with a little bit of WinAPI)

It appears that your code is dependent on being run from (or being connected to) a console that the text can be rendered to. A screensaver should ideally have a canvas of some description that covers the screen where the animation can be rendered.
